# How to create a function in PHP

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to create a function called `saveorder`. This is my code so far:

```
<?php
//function foo($arg_1, $arg_2, /* ..., */ $arg_n)
function saveorder($orderid,$txnid,$date,$amount)
{
    $a_str = array( 
        "orderid"=>"175", 
        "txnid"=>"RC456456456", 
        "date"=>"54156456465", 
        "amount"=>"109$" 
    ); 

    $file = 'order.dat';

    $contents = implode("|", $a_str);

    $contents .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
}
echo "function will return=".saveorder($orderid);
?>
```

I think I'm doing it wrong because I never created my own function. Still, however, I want to create this function to save the order in the `order.dat` file. Can anyone please help me create this function? I'm trying very hard but I'm unable to create it.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you are asking for!

Comment: To the down-voter: This is a brand new user. Please provide a comment to help them become a better user.

Comment: @Diff.Thinkr:) question edited

Comment: David, so far you are doing well as this is your first comment... As for what you wanting it to do, could you clarify please?

Comment: He, he. I love questions with simple titles... and then you read the whole question. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't return anything.

Apart from that the function is okay:

```
function saveorder($orderid,$txnid,$date,$amount){
    $a_str = array( 
        "orderid"=>$orderid, 
        "txnid"=>$txnid, 
        "date"=>$date, 
        "amount"=>$amount 
    ); 

    $file = 'order.dat';
    $contents = implode("|", $a_str);

    $contents .= PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($file, $contents, FILE_APPEND);
    return $contents;
}
echo "function will return=".saveorder("175","RC456456456","54156456465","109$");
```

Comment: @Mihai Iorga:) but my order.dat file always remains same 175|RC456456456|54156456465|109$ , Actually  i want to change when i change the order nd keep my new order in the new line

Comment: @Marc Towler@Mihai Iorga175|RC456456456|54156456465|109$, 176|RC456123456|54156989635|250$ nd so on 177|........ in my order.dat file

Comment: leave only one ``PHP_EOL`` -> ``$contents .= PHP_EOL;`` and add ``FILE_APPEND`` to ``file_put_contents`` -> ``file_put_contents($file, $contents, FILE_APPEND);``

Comment: i m working this file_put_contents($file, $contents, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); but when i delete this LOCK_EX its working

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you didn't return any value in your function, so it did run correctly.

You need add like following statment at the end of function

```
<?php
function saveorder($orderid,$txnid,$date,$amount) //function foo($arg_1, $arg_2, /* ..., */ $arg_n) {
    $a_str = array(    "orderid"=>"175",    "txnid"=>"RC456456456",    "date"=>"54156456465",    "amount"=>"109$"  );
    $file = 'order.dat';
    $contents = implode("|", $a_str);
    $contents .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    res = file_put_contents($file, $contents);
    if(res){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
echo "function will return=".saveorder($orderid);
?>
```